# How come arrow function can by pass the Function signature when assigned?

Tags: flutter, dart

I can assign an arrow function, which returns a value to a function variable that requires a void signature. But I can not assign a block function that returns a value. Why? Should the not be arrow function restricted as well, as it returns a value?

[arrow function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1vDV.png)

[block function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjtNj.png)

Comment: Please do not post the image or screenshot instead copy and paste the entire code- [reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) also take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because by doing

```
void Function(int) function=(a)=>b=a;
```

Dart assumes that you don't want to return the value of the assignation, that normally you could use, for example:

```dart
void main() {
  int a=10,b;
  print(b=a);
}
```

So, dart just thinks that you want to assign the variable, nothing more. Another more detailed example here:

```dart
int number=10;
late int target;

void main() {
  print(test());
  number+=10;
  test2();  
  print(target);
}


int test()=>target=number;

void test2()=>target=number;

//Note: there aren't many best practices here (For example, global variables)
//Is just an example to make you understand, nothing more
```

but if you specify the return, dart will think you reeeeally want to return that value, and that's not possible, as it is a void function.

Comment: Thanks for that, is there any particular place in the dart documentation where you could find this info?

Comment: Not particularly, i just know this because it's been quite a long time i use dart :)
If you've found the answer helpful, upvote it and mark it as the answer! :)